# jQuery: Change css class on click

Tags: jquery

I try to change a css class on click. But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="tags">
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">Watchlist</span>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">Watched</span>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">Like</span>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $( "#tags" ).click(function() {
        .find("span")
        .removeClass("badge-secondary")
        .addClass("badge-primary");
    });
</script>
```

I am thankful for every hint.

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: yes. i did. other things are working. :)

Comment: Should be a big error right there in your console.... use your developer tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) directly on spans:

```js
$( "#tags span" ).on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('badge-secondary badge-primary')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="tags">
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">Watchlist</span>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">Watched</span>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">Like</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is working. thank you. BUT: i want to use the css of bootstrap. any idea on how to do that? the secondary bootstrap badge should change to the primary bootstarp badge.

Comment: last question: this code just works in any browser. but it is not working on my local mamp?

Comment: try to look in the console and mamp console.

Comment: Closing bracket missing. ;)